# How do I specify a column when subsetting in a function?

Tags: r, function, subset

```
#create a list of data I want to take the grand mean of
A2 <- c(A2_M_fish1, A2_A_fish2, A2_M_fish3, A2_A_fish4)

#create an empty vector to put the grandmeans in
A2_values <- numeric(4)

#make a function to pull out the four last values and get the means
datamean <- function(x)
   {
     y <- subset(x, Loop>=7 & Loop<=10, select=c(MO2))
   mean(y$MO2)
   }
```

So in the previous function, I reference "Loop" which is the name of a column in each of the data frames I will be using in my loop. I don't know how to specify that column in the loop because when I run it as shown it tells me:

```
 Error in subset.default(x, Loop >= 7 & Loop <= 10, select = c(MO2)) : 
  object 'Loop' not found
```

But when I run it like this:

```
datamean <- function(x)
   {
     y <- subset(x, x$Loop>=7 & x$Loop<=10, select=c(MO2))
   mean(y$MO2)
}
```

It just give me this error:

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: Where are they Loop and MO2 variables coming from? They aren't in your data

Comment: Loop and MO2 are columns in the data frames: A2_M_fish1, A2_A_fish2, A2_M_fish3, A2_A_fish4

Comment: oooh, your running a list through the function? Then you need to unlist them or use a for loop to run through each of them. Youcan't just put an entire list of dataframes in

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `y[, "MO2"]` in loops rather than the `$` like this:

```
 datamean <- function(x)
 {
   y <- subset(x, x[ , "Loop"]>=7 & x[ , "Loop"]<=10, select=c("MO2"))
   mean(y[ , "MO2"])
 }
```

Let me know if you still have the issue

Comment: I made those changes and got a new different error:  Error in x[, "Loop"] : incorrect number of dimensions